# What "find out" implies in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

> The Times: last Sunday night I turned on the TV **to find out**
>   what was happening in Libya

Does this means that I turned on the TV intentionally to know what is happening in Libya because I heard about it and I wanted to know more, or it implies that I didn't have any idea what was going on in Libya, and I started to learn about it when I turned on the TV.

Comment: _To = In order to_ implies that you knew _something_ was happening in Libya and wanted to learn about it in more detail, or to hear the latest developments.

Comment: So @KateBunting, if I had known about the story for the first time when I turned on the TV and I want to give this impression, what should I say instead of to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, the statement implies that you had prior knowledge that something was happening in Libya, and you turned the TV on specifically to get more information.

If you were to say this instead (using '... and found out ...' as per Kate Bunting's suggestion in the comments):

"Last Sunday night I turned on the TV, and found out what was happening in Libya."

[it would imply that you turned on the TV, and then found out that something was happening in Libya that you had not previously known about.]

The above is not true with the change to using 'and found out' so not exactly the same, but it sounds better.  Stick with the original version of this reply if you want to be explicit that you did not know previously.

If that is all too confusing, blame the retarded culture of editing previously posted replies :-)

Hope that helps,

Alan.

Comment: Or simply "...and found out..."

Comment: Yes - I agree that, "... and found out ..." is better :-)

Comment: @Alan please edit your answer with "and found out", so others can learn from this. Thanks :)

Comment: I have edited as requested, but the whole conversation is now less understandable due to the changes.  Not sure if those that may follow can uncover the actual sequence of posts as they were at the time of posting, but if they can, I recommend doing that, and ignoring the final version.  If there is a better option (show original and show final versions perhaps?) I would love to know how to do that - I'm probably missing something obvious as uaual!